# Usar datos de una tabla para login

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Quiero usar los datos de una tabla en SQL Server para verificar los datos de usuario, si esta registrado o no. Ya logro conectar a la base de datos, y guardar los datos, ¿qué debo hacer?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   // SEARCH USER

        string s = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cadenaconexion1"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(s);
        conexion.Open();
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("select * from usuario" +
              " where nick ='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", conexion);
        SqlDataReader registro = comando.ExecuteReader();
        //SqlDataReader registro1 = comando.ExecuteReader();

        if (registro.Read())
        {
            Label1.Text = "nick:" + registro["nick"] + "<br>" +
                          "pass:" + registro["pass"];
            conexion.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
            conexion.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podes ser mas claro? ahi ya estas buscando al usuario por nombre, si agregas el pass ya sirve

Comment: pero al momento de ingresar el usuario con otra pass me deja avanzar y no debería. la PK de la tabla es usuario.

Comment: Bienvenido, lo único que tendrías que hacer para ver si el usuario ingresado ya esta registrado, es agregar `pass` a tu condición `WHERE`, de ahí, si devuelve una fila, efectivamente existe, sino, no

Comment: gracias, son los mejores!! seguiré molestando con este tema.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta agregarle la condición de la contraseña.
Con esa query te estas asegurando unicamente que el usuario exista pero te falta tambien validar la contraseña... es decir que te falta agregar una condición en el where. Quedaria mas o menos asi:  `new SqlCommand(String.Format("Select * from usuario where nick = '{0}' and pass  = '{1}'",TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text),conexion);`
Estoy teniendo en cuenta que TextBox1 es el campo para el usuario y TextBox2 es el campo para la contraseña.
Saludos!